# How to throttle ngxs @Select observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I'm building an [application](https://github.com/datenknoten/ngx-ssb-client) using ngxs as my state manager. My app displays a feed of messages which are paginated, but all messages are in the state, which are about 1000 in my case.  I have [a selector](https://github.com/datenknoten/ngx-ssb-client/blob/develop/src/pages/public-feed/public-feed.component.ts#L85) which paginates the posts, but when the app initialy loads, I have a hugh perfomance drain, as the posts come in.

I tried something radical like this:

```
    this.currentFeedSettings = this
        .store
        .select(CurrentFeedSettingState)
        .pipe(
            throttleTime(10000),
        );
```

But some messages are shown almost instantly, but not after 10 seconds. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: maybe you want to `delay` instead of  `throttle`, as throttle emits the first time and throttle the subsequent values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the [debounce](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounce) operator.

> debounce delays values emitted by the source Observable, but drops previous pending delayed emissions if a new value arrives on the source Observable. This operator keeps track of the most recent value from the source Observable, and spawns a duration Observable by calling the durationSelector function.

In your code, that would look like:

```js
this.store
  .select(CurrentFeedSettingState)
  .pipe(debounceTime(100))
  .subscribe((res) => { ... });
```